# Fabric JS load ploygon from local json file

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I found this http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/fmgXt/ example on loading rect and circle,

```
// Do some initializing stuff
fabric.Object.prototype.

set({
  transparentCorners: false,
  cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
  cornerSize: 12,
  padding: 5
});

// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var json = '{"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":300,"top":150,"width":150,"height":150,"fill":"#29477F","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":{"color":"rgba(94, 128, 191, 0.5)","blur":5,"offsetX":10,"offsetY":10},"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"rx":0,"ry":0,"x":0,"y":0},{"type":"circle","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":300,"top":400,"width":200,"height":200,"fill":"rgb(166,111,213)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":{"color":"#5b238A","blur":20,"offsetX":-20,"offsetY":-10},"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"radius":100}],"background":""}'

canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
  fabric.log(o, object);
});
```

and I need to load polygon from json, how do i do it?

Comment: It is the same as rect or circle, you need to pass the fabric.Polygon json object to loadFromJSON.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { width: 600, height: 600, backgroundColor: '#e4ede6' });

const json = {"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":300,"top":150,"width":150,"height":150,"fill":"#29477F","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":{"color":"rgba(94, 128, 191, 0.5)","blur":5,"offsetX":10,"offsetY":10},"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"rx":0,"ry":0,"x":0,"y":0},{"type":"circle","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":300,"top":400,"width":200,"height":200,"fill":"rgb(166,111,213)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":{"color":"#5b238A","blur":20,"offsetX":-20,"offsetY":-10},"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"radius":100}],"background":""};

(async () => {
  const objects = await new Promise(resolve => fabric.util.enlivenObjects(json.objects, resolve));
  canvas.add(...objects)
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.6.0/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).